# Unable to install some apps from memory card

Tags: 8.0, lumia, apps, store, sd-card

I brought a new Lumia that runs Windows Phone 8 and now I am trying to install apps by manually downloading them and then installing it through the SD card (Store > SD card). I have installed some of the apps like Viber this way.

But I am unable to install other kinds of apps like Adobe Reader, [PDF Reader](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/pdf-reader/1a28bfcf-9f04-46d2-8532-3a338a5dc23b), [German](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/learn-german-for-beginners/3121f37f-b6bc-4f01-9855-1cecbf7c36b6) etc. The problem is that my phone doesn't recognize the XAP files of these apps. it just showing "identifying apps" and nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried download them again?

Comment: Were these XAPs downloaded from the Windows Store, or from somewhere else?

Comment: @VitorCanova yes, i again downloaded apps from windows store and now its working. It seems at a particlar time windows store allow only a selected number of apps to be installed. Sometimes **store>sd card** will be invisible even if XAP files of apps are present in memory card

Comment: Installing apps on a Windows Phone external storage is impossible.

Comment: @air-dex it soon will be possible, as this feature is in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: @Eka It may be worth rewording that as an answer and flagging it as accepted, to help other people that experience the same problem as you.

Comment: I have the same issue in 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/8611/106