# I can not install apps from the SD card

Tags: apps, store, sd-card

I can not install apps from the SD card, when I try to install one it shows the message...

> "we are having a trouble installing this app"

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Where did you get the apps from?Is your phone set to the same region as the store you downloaded them from?

Comment: which app is this?

Comment: If you are using an account created with a different region, this could be part of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons:

- The developer of this app does not allow to install (or access) to SD Card.
- Your SD card has error, try to reset it and install the app again.
- If this app is developed by you and you deploy it from Visual Studio, I think that there is a problem about unlock your device.

I hope my answer can help you !

Comment: In addition to your answer , application installation will fail if there is more than one file in phone and any problem in  internet connection ...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are **connected to internet** before installing the app form SD card. You cannot install apps when you are ofline.